# Plotting a dataset with condition over a column in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I would like to plot the following dataset.

```
+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+----+----+--------------------+-------------------+----+----+----+----+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------------+------+
|   time_stamp_0|sender_ip_1|receiver_ip_2|count|rank|  xi|                  pi|                  r| ip5| ip4| ip3| ip2|            variance|             entropy|    pre_chi_square|          chi_square| total_chi_square|attack|
+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+----+----+--------------------+-------------------+----+----+----+----+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------------+------+
|10:37:37.000985|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1| 9345|   1|1796|1.070090957731407...|0.19218833600856072|1211|1157|4812|1796|6.982982177427692E-5|9.783410080138751E-4|3.3954177346722574|0.001890544395697248|13.58167093868903|     1|
|10:37:37.000995|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1| 9345|   2|1796|2.140181915462814...|0.19218833600856072|1211|1157|4812|1796|3.497253089848578...|0.001808335909968907| 17.00510593066335|0.009468321787674473|13.58167093868903|     1|
|10:37:37.001002|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.1| 9345|   3|1796|3.210272873194221...|0.19218833600856072|1211|1157|4812|1796|8.436389877417202E-4| 0.00258233850119472|41.021252923981834|0.022840341271704808|13.58167093868903|     1|
```

I need to have a plot that shows me the "rank" over the "time_stamp_0" only for sender_ip_1="10.0.0.3". 
I have the following code:

```
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
set format x '%H:%M:%S'
//I have a problem with the below code
plot  "test.txt" using 1:($2=="10.0.0.3"?$5:1/0)
```

However the plotted graph is not correct. 
In fact, it seems that, no filtering applies on the data and the graph is as same as the graph without filtering!

I should mention that, the dataframe is inside a file (test.txt) and it does't have any  header.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `eq` for string equality checking and `strcol` to get the string value of a column:

```
plot  "test.txt" using 1:(strcol(2) eq "10.0.0.3" ? $5 : 1/0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into two problems:

- The string-equality operator in Gnuplot is `eq`, not `==`.
- Data extracted for plotting is not of the string type (I assume it’s a float), so you cannot apply string operations to it.

I don’t see a way to solve the second problem from within Gnuplot. You can however pipe everything through something like AWK before plotting to handle the condition for you:

```
plot "<awk '{print $1, ($2==\"10.0.0.3\" ? $5 : \"nan\")}' test.dat" u 1:2
```

(Note that you still have to take care of your ASCII table formatting, e.g., by removing all `|` characters via SED.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well it gave me the following error:                        input record number 4097, file u_output.txt
 source line number 1
                                                                                 ^
         Need full using spec for x time data

Comment: @Queen: Then heed the error message. (Also see my edit.)